# Not understanding linked list output

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm struggling a bit to conceptually understand what is going on in the code for a leetcode solution:

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next


class Solution(object):
    def deleteDuplicates(self, head):
        temp = head
        while (temp and temp.next):
            if (temp.next.val == temp.val):
                temp.next = temp.next.next
                continue
            temp = temp.next
        return head
```

I don't understand when a copy of the head node is added to temp variable, all these changes occur, but nothing is done with the head in the logic, head isn't even in the while loop, but then you return the head and suddenly its sorted.

What's going on under the hood? why is the head tag getting sorted and is accepted by leetcode when it looks like it isn't even being manipulated? What is going on why does this solution work?

Comment: _nothing is done with the head in the logic_ Wrong, because of `temp = head`.  When the loop starts, `temp` and `head` are _the same node_.

Comment: You say "a copy of the head node". There is no copy. Assignment never copies data in Python. The object connected with `head` just gets the additional name `temp`. You might want to read: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: @JohnGordon thank you. It just came to me intuitively just a few minutes ago, and then I read your comment to validate it. Thanks again

Comment: @Matthias thanks, having a read. Yeah, basically I thought it was a rebinding instead of a mutation.

Answer (score 1):

Well this deletes adjacent duplicates, it does not sort anything. If there are adjacent duplicates, the first one is kept. That's why `head` will always stay `head` and it *is* manipulated:

```
temp.next = temp.next.next
```

In this line, `temp` can well be `head` (`temp = head` after all) and it is relinked to the second next node if the next node holds the same value.

And if you are keen on getting rid of `head`, e.g. by removing preceding dupes, you could go with this brief recursive approach:

```
class Solution:
    def deleteDuplicates(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        if head:
            head.next = self.deleteDuplicates(head.next)
            if head.next and head.val == head.next.val:
                return head.next
        return head
```

Comment: _it does not sort anything_ OP may have been using "sorted" in the British English sense, which means "problem solved".  i.e. _Bob and I had a misunderstanding, but now it's sorted._

Comment: Did not consider that =) good we've got that *straightened*

Comment: @user2390182 yeah sorry I meant sorted like "it's working"